# Error 400 Flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I am getting error 400 when i load my website, i have check everything and nothing seems off. 
Thanks

Error:

> Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

What the code does:
It takes a input from a user, that is then saved in a file for use of tracking what a user orders from my drinks machine

```
import flask
from flask import request
@app.route('/Half1File', methods=['POST']) 
def Half1File():
    print(request.form['projectFilepath'])
    Name = request.form['projectFilepath']
    print(Name)
    file = open("Tab.txt", "a")
    file.write('\n'+Name + ", Drink1Half")
    return
    print (Name)

@app.route("/Half1Tab") 
def Half1Tab():
    return """<html>
    <form action="/Half1File" method="post">
    Project file path: <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </html>"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix the name of the value passed to `request` in your form, and provide a view in the return statement (i made it *easy*).

```
import flask
from flask import request
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/Half1File', methods=['POST'])
def Half1File():
    print(request.form)
    print(request.form['Name'])
    Name = request.form['Name']
    print(Name)
    file = open("Tab.txt", "a")
    file.write('\n'+Name + ", Drink1Half")
    return """<html><div>OK : {} </div></html>""".format(Name)

@app.route("/Half1Tab")
def Half1Tab():
    return """<html>
    <form action="/Half1File" method="post">
    Project file path: <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </html>"""
```

Comment: I know i'm not meant to but thank you very much, spent an hour wondering how the hell to do it! The way you explained it was also very informative and helpful
I can now finally get the website full functional